# How can i send OTP to users phone number in Laravel just before registration

Tags: laravel

I already have a function that takes a phone number and sends OTP to the number in laravel..

But now i want to be able to send OTP to phone number during registration in laravel...i am thinking this will be at this point of creating the users information below....

Please help as i am not sure at what stage to send the OTP and verify it too.

I already have a function that takes a phone number and sends OTP to the number in laravel..

protected function create(array $data)
    {

```
    $otp = rand(100000, 999999);
    $MSG91 = new MSG91();

    $msg91Response = $MSG91->sendSMS($otp,$users['mobile']);


    return User::create([

        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'customers_telephone' => $data['mobile'],
        'customers_firstname' => $data['fname'],
        'customers_lastname' => $data['lname'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
    ]);
}
```

What i want to archieve is to send OTP to the user and let the user verify the OTP before users can access the dashboard

Answer (score 0):

To solve your issue, you need to add a `otp_verified` field in your users table as `Boolean`. Example if `0` means not yet verify and `1` is verified.

Then when a user logged in, they will not proceed in the dashboard instead a popup or redirected to a page where they need to put the otp with a submit button that needs to verify the otp.

If it's success then redirect the user to the dashboard.

Comment: Are you using `AJAX` on the registration?

Comment: If it's not an ajax, then you need to have a button where if a user clicks it will send an otp, and store the otp in a session. Then add a validation on the registration where you need to check if the session otp is matches the users input otp.